# Why might my custom soundcloud player not make sound on an iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I have this testing area here:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/RPbpQZ

Besides needing a bunch of js refactoring, now that I've been playing with the API, I'm happy with what is going on.

It works great in CodePen on my laptop, but on my phone, it is silent.

It's not auto play. Just a click event.

I've tried in debug mode --- and a few other CodePen options... in case it's an origin thing... any ideas? The code is just basic stuff, so I think it's something else.

```
SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
  sound.play();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a really similar problem with the custom player that I was developing. I would work perfectly on desktop, but on mobile it wouldn't play on the first click. It would play however when I paused it and then pressed play again.

I was trying to run the debugMode so I could see what the difference was between desktop and mobile. I couldn't get the debugMode to work, without linking to the soundmanager JS as well. As soon as I added it the player worked perfectly on mobile too.

Not sure what the root issue was, but it seems that you need to load the soundmanager JS along with the SoundCloud SDK and to get all of the functionality. Doesn't really get to the bottom of it, but I hope it helps.

Comment: It does help. Thanks. It's misleading that the soundcloud SDK docs say that it will load Sound Manager 2. The whole docs are misleading and convoluted. v1 and v2 should have clear boundaries. I have things working now actually, but I'm still trying to clarify *why* it's working.

Comment: Yeah I felt exactly the same, Its a shame the the docs are so misleading. I thought it might be down to the flash player trying to load on mobile, and then falling back to html5, but it is pretty hard to tell without the debugger.

Comment: I have 3 test versions... and some work and some don't  /  so I'm trying to cross reference and see what the issue is... http://sheriffderek.consulting/dev/c2/ has no link to soundmanager2 /  and works... I'm unsure why my codepen will not function.

Comment: The links I'm using are soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js & connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js. I haven't had any other issues yet. I have no idea why it wouldn't work on code pen.